# Continuous Subarray Sum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to learn Kotlin these days and thought of converting my Java leetcode solutions into kotlin to understand the syntax and practice its nuances. I am still facing issues with Collections. Below is the code for one of the famous interview problem Continuous Subarray Sum.
Details about use cases: https://leetcode.com/problems/continuous-subarray-sum/

```
class Solution {
    fun checkSubarraySum(nums: IntArray, k: Int): Boolean {
        
        var map = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
        var sum = 0
        map.put(0,-1)
        for (i in 0 until nums.size-1){
            sum += nums[i]
            
            if (k != 0){
                sum = sum % k
            }
            
            if (map.containsKey(sum)){
                if (i - map.get(sum) > 1){
                    return true
                }
            }
            else{
                map.put(sum,i)
            }
        }
        
        return false
    }
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
Line 15: Char 25: error: type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected
                if (i - map.get(sum) > 1){
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Please note that I am really new to this language so this question might be dumb.               ^

Comment: `Map.get` returns null if the key doesn't exist, so `map.get(sum)` could be null, so you can't perform arithmetic with it. You can read more about nullability in Kotlin here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: You've obviously effectively checked for this case with `map.containsKey...` but the compiler isn't smart enough to infer this, so you can either get rid of the contains check and use the nullable return, or assert it as non-null yourself.

Comment: @HenryTwist Thank you Henry. I have posted the solution. Can you let me know if my thought process is right?

Comment: Yes exactly. In Kotlin there is either `Type` or `Type?` depending on whether it can be null or not. If you want a few more Kotlin tips, you can use `map[sum]` to get and `map[sum] = i` to put. You also shouldn't use `var` unless you really need a variable, your map can be a `val` here. You can also use `mutableMapOf(0 to -1)`.

Comment: Thanks @HenryTwist. Will surely modify the code. Cheers!

Comment: @HenryTwist It's not only a matter of the compiler being smart enough;  another thread could modify the map in between.  Another cause of `get()` returning null after `containsKey()` returned true would be a dodgy implementation of Map that didn't follow the contract.  (And, if the map's value is nullable, a mapping to a null value would be a third cause.)

Comment: Since the map is contained within the scope of the function and isn’t passed to any closure, it could *not* be modified by some other thread. The compiler is able to smart-cast local `var`s if it sees they aren’t being passed to a closure. It theoretically could be smart enough to detect that the value must exist in the Map here, but that’s probably too sophisticated to be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Thank you @HenryTwist
Int is a nullable entity denoted by Int? and I am trying to access Int here: So that's the reason compiler needs '!!' (non-null asserted)

```
class Solution {
    fun checkSubarraySum(nums: IntArray, k: Int): Boolean {
        
        var map = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
        var sum = 0
        map.put(0,-1)
        
        for (i in 0 until nums.size){
            sum += nums[i]
            
            if (k != 0){
                sum = sum % k
            }
            
            if (map.containsKey(sum)){
                if (i - map.get(sum)!! > 1){
                    return true
                }
            }
            else{
                map.put(sum,i)
            }
        }
        
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does indeed answer the question, using `!!` is often a code smell, indicating that there's a better approach.  In this case, one option would be to replace that section of code with something like `map.getOrNull(sum)?.let{ if (it == null) … else if (i - it > 1) … }`.

Comment: @gidds Thanks for the answer, but I am not that advanced yet. Would wish to write such pieces someday. For now, I am getting used to the syntax and concepts. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: What's the `getOrNull` function you're referring to @gidds? As far as I am aware that doesn't exist for a `Map`? Also inside the `let`, `it` can't be null?

Comment: @gidds didn't get that function getOrNull either..tried using it in compiler.

Comment: What I think they meant was this: `map[sum].let{ if (it == null) ... else if (i - it > 1) ... }`